# Rejoin Categorical Labels After Running Cluster Analysis

Tags: scikit-learn, k-nn

I'm working on creating a kNN & PCA analysis using 6 variables associated with different schools.

The first step is to drop the school name label column which the first column, so only numeric values remain:

```
random sample of 10 obervations only features
features = new_df[new_df.columns[1:9]]
features.sample(10)
```

```
# Create a model based on 3 centroids
model = KMeans(n_clusters = 3, init= 'k-means++', n_init=100, max_iter=1000)
# Fit the data and predict the cluster assignment for each data point
km_clusters = model.fit_predict(features.values)
# View the cluster assigments
km_clusters
```

Then fit the data and I get the clusters. So my question is, how do I re-join the school name to the output with the assigned cluster label so I know which school was assigned to each?

It seems like index is still in tact and in order, is it safe to use that and rejoin the dataframes?

Comment: Yes, it is safe to re-join the school name to the output with the assigned cluster label.